# Two char array getting inputs with spaces one by one

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, fgets

Input:
Enter name: Arun kumar
Enter txt: I am good at programming!I think!

I just try to get the name and text. Like,

```
char *ch[2]; \\I tried changing it to char ch[20] for name and 
ch[100] for text
printf("Enter name:");
fgets(ch[0],20,stdin);
printf("Enter text:");
fgets(ch[1],100,stdin);
```

But it doesn't  work fine. The code just stops working when run the program. Also suggest a best way of doing it.

Comment: Try `char ch[2][100];` If you want two strings in the same (2D) array, then they need to be the same (maximum) size.

Comment: Yeah it works fine when I try as a separate code .

Comment: But when I used insert my code it directly goes for the second fgets why!

Comment: It is rather unclear as to what you are asking, and what your expected output and desired program structure should be. Please try to clarify the question, and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [char *ch 2](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*ch%5B2%5D) is two pointers to uninitialized memory; passing them to `fgets` causes undefined behaviour. Otoh, [char ch 2 100](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+ch%5B2%5D%5B100%5D) causes much more space to be reserved; `fgets` uses the space to fill the input.

Comment: Sorry guys I got my solution! I used two fgets one by one the first fgets takes the space from the printf above it. So I just add fflush(stdin) then everything works fine!..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the goal is to create an array containing two strings of unequal length. This "array of arrays" cannot be declared directly, but there are two ways of accomplishing the same thing:

- Declaring two static arrays and then copying a pointer to each array in a new array with 2 elements. This is not recommended, as you may as well use the pointers directly (which would be fine) and avoid potential problems regarding the `restrict` keyword or strict aliasing.
- Using dynamic memory allocation for each array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void staticMemoryAndAlias()
{
    char ch0[20];
    char ch1[100];

    char *ch[2] = {ch0, ch1};

    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(ch[0], 20U, stdin);
    printf("Enter text:");
    fgets(ch[1], 100U, stdin);

    printf("Name: %s", ch[0]);
    printf("Text: %s", ch[1]);
}

void dynamicMemoryAllocation()
{
    size_t const chSize0 = 20U;
    size_t const chSize1 = 100U;

    char *ch[2];
    ch[0] = (char*) malloc(chSize0);
    if (ch[0] == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    ch[1] = (char*) malloc(chSize1);
    if (ch[1] == NULL)
    {
        free(ch[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(ch[0], chSize0, stdin);
    printf("Enter text:");
    fgets(ch[1], chSize0, stdin);

    printf("Name: %s", ch[0]);
    printf("Text: %s", ch[1]);

    free(ch[0]);
    free(ch[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    staticMemoryAndAlias();
    dynamicMemoryAllocation();
}
```

What is "the best" depends on the larger context. How large do the buffers need to be? How do you want to deal with input that is larger than the size of the buffer? Do the entire strings need to remain in memory or will we only extract some information for further parsing/processing? Etc.

Given your code snippet and (small) example input, I would probably start with separate static buffers and extend the code depending on the context:

```
char ch0[20];
printf("Enter name: ");
fgets(ch0, 20U, stdin);

printf("Enter text:");
char ch1[100];
fgets(ch1, 100U, stdin);

printf("Name: %s", ch0);
printf("Text: %s", ch1);
```